# Getting a new iPhone 5 and handing down my old 4S

Tags: iphone

My wife is getting an iPhone 5 next week and I have the iPhone 4S. I will use the new phone and she is going to use my old 4S.

I'm new to the iPhone world, so this may be a dumb question but how do I keep my photos, contacts, etc. without it all popping up again when she syncs her iPhone? Will I have a new iCloud and she have mine? Or will that all change also? Will the apps come back or do they delete?

I don't want any old contacts texing her or old photos popping up when its her phone!

Answer (score 1):

Back up the 4S (either to your computer or iCloud), then when you set up the 5, select to restore from the old 4S backup. That will restore your iCloud account, and all apps and content.

Once the 5 has been successfully set up with your content, wipe the 4s (*Settings → Reset → Erase All Content and Settings*) and set it up from scratch, with a new iCloud account for your wife (unless she has an existing one).

It's important to note that your phone account is tied to the SIM card in the phone, so calls and SMSes sent to your existing number will still go to the iPhone 4S, and the iPhone 5 will be linked to your wife's account. To change this, you need to swap the SIM cards, which is easy to do, **except** the iPhone 4S uses a micro-SIM, whereas the 5 uses a nano-SIM. You're likely going to need to talk with your phone provider to reprogram the SIMs, or get new ones of the proper sizes.

Comment: would it be easy enought to change sim cards etc? i dont want old flames getting in touch with her by mistake lol wink wink

Comment: Changing SIMs is dead easy. The phone comes with a tool to eject the card, though a bent paper clip should do just as well. (I haven't checked the iphone 5, though I expect it to be the same.) You are aware that you are posting in a public forum under what seems to be your real name, right? Nudge nudge.